# iPad Camera Connection kit?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipad

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the iPad's camera connection kit? I would like to read the files off the connected mass storage device. Would this be possible or is this something that only Apple can do in their apps.

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old question, but google brought me here so I thought I'd add [this link](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/04/29/ipad-hacksugar-more-than-you-wanted-or-needed-to-know-about-a/) for the next person to come along.

> The good news is this. USB drives do mount properly and show up in the system as /dev/disk2s1. Yay. You can even add more drives via a hub. The iPad supports both FAT and HFS+ drives.
>
> The bad news is this. As iPhone developer Dustin Howett discovered,
>   that mount point is sandboxed away from normal developer use. You
>   cannot read from or write to that disk using standard iPhone SDK
>   applications.

Comment: Single-link answers are discouraged here, please add at least a summary of the linked-too article to prevent bitrot making this question useless. I'd do it, but I don't know anything about the iWorld, so I don't know what the relevant part is.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Summary Added.