# How can I implement an alternative to iTunes file sharing on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, file-sharing

I need to transfer files from an iPad in "Airplane Mode" (such that neither Bluetooth, nor WLAN nor GSM are available) to a laptop/desktop running Windows or MacOS.

I hope to implement this as an alternative to [iTunes file sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094) for iPad developers, *specifically* those in the Enterprise Program (so no App Store concerns over the use of dodgy techniques or private APIs).

I know that there exist file browsers for jailbroken phones, but other than jailbreaking, is there any viable way to transfer files from within an app?

I would even consider "bizarre" solutions that go through the camera adapter.

Comment: Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528097/accessing-ios-filesystem-for-mac or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728347/ipad-can-i-write-plist-to-external-storage or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041278/ipad-camera-connection-kit?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Update]** In principle it is possible to build the needed hardware/software by signing up for an Apple program called [MFi](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) ("Made for i*").

Although I have not yet found a hardware/library which allows arbitrary data transfers out of the box, there is a solution for a similar problem: A company named RedPark offers [a cable which accesses RS232 devices through the Dock Connector](http://www.redpark.com/c2db9.html). This solution can be combined with a USB to RS232 adapter which then allows data exchange.