# Accessing iOS filesystem for Mac

Tags: macos, filesystems

I was trying out the mac app DiskAid and found it does everything that I need to be able to do in the app I am writing.  DiskAid appears to have complete access to the filesystem on my iPad.  This is not limited to the shared files by the applications on the iPad - not by a long shot.  DiskAid sees all the files for every app on the device (sharer or otherwise).  It is also not limited to files in the Documents directory for each app.  It sees all files down to root level.

I was also amazed when I discovered that iTunes doesn't even have to be running for all of this to work.  Also I don't recall having to authenticate in any way (apple ID or anything like that)  I just plug in the device via usb and away she goes.

I've been searching for days now and have not found anything that even hints that this is even possible.  Yet we know it is.

Does anyone have any idea how they are pulling this off.  By the way my device is not jailbroken.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: how did you see the root level (/)? or do you just mean the app root level?

Answer (score 1):

There is info [DigiDNA blog](http://blog.digidna.net/post/45110799512/itunes-pairing-is-a-security-issue) that what they use is Apple Mobile Device Service library, which they say function as driver to Apple device. A google search to the library brought me to the [Iphone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library) site about reverse engineered C header files needed to link to the library. Hope it will be useful.